# What's the fastest, most efficient, and pythonic way to perform a mathematical sigma sum?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, math, sum

Let's say that I want to perform a mathematical summation, say the [Madhava–Leibniz formula for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80), in Python:

[image: generated by latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%5Capprox%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5Ek%7D%7B2k+1%7D]

Within a function called Leibniz_pi(), I could create a loop to calculate the n<sup>th</sup> partial sum, such as:

```
def Leibniz_pi(n):
    nth_partial_sum = 0       #initialize the variable
    for i in range(n+1):
        nth_partial_sum += ((-1)**i)/(2*i + 1)
    return nth_partial_sum
```

I'm assuming it would be faster to use something like xrange() instead of range(). Would it be even faster to use numpy and its built in numpy.sum() method? What would such an example look like?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? There is no `xrange` in Python 3.

Comment: The best way to get your answer is to implement the alternatives and measure the time they are taking. The timeit module might be helpful.

Comment: @gmds I'm a Python novice, and am familiar with Python 2 -- however, I don't mind if the answer isn't Python 2 focused.

Comment: numpy will certainly be faster.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Wouldn't it take time to create the necessary numpy array(s) before any calculation is completed? I'm a numpy novice.

Comment: @I_Don't_Code In general, for operations involving collections of more than a few elements, where those operations can be performed in parallel, `numpy` will be much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess most people will define the fastest solution by @zero using only numpy as the most pythonic, but it is certainly not the fastest. With some additional optimizations you can beat the already fast numpy implementation by a factor of 50.

**Using only Numpy  (@zero)**

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import numba as nb

def Leibniz_point(n):
    val = (-1)**n / (2*n + 1)
    return val

%timeit Leibniz_point(np.arange(1000)).sum()
33.8 µs ± 203 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Make use of numexpr**

```
n=np.arange(1000)
%timeit ne.evaluate("sum((-1)**n / (2*n + 1))")
21 µs ± 354 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Compile your function using Numba**

```
# with error_model="numpy", turns off division-by-zero checks 
@nb.njit(error_model="numpy",cache=True)
def Leibniz_pi(n):
  nth_partial_sum = 0.       #initialize the variable as float64
  for i in range(n+1):
      nth_partial_sum += ((-1)**i)/(2*i + 1)
  return nth_partial_sum

%timeit Leibniz_pi(999)
6.48 µs ± 38.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Edit, optimizing away the costly (-1)**n**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

#replacement for the much more costly (-1)**n
@nb.njit()
def sgn(i):
    if i%2>0:
        return -1.
    else:
        return 1.

# with error_model="numpy", turns off the division-by-zero checks
#
# fastmath=True makes SIMD-vectorization in this case possible
# floating point math is in general not commutative
# e.g. calculating four times sgn(i)/(2*i + 1) at once and then the sum 
# is not exactly the same as doing this sequentially, therefore you have to
# explicitly allow the compiler to make the optimizations

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",cache=True)
def Leibniz_pi(n):
    nth_partial_sum = 0.       #initialize the variable
    for i in range(n+1):
        nth_partial_sum += sgn(i)/(2*i + 1)
    return nth_partial_sum

%timeit Leibniz_pi(999)
777 ns ± 5.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is all very interesting! Thank you. Question: You used ```ne.evaluate("sum((-1)**n / (2*n + 1))")```, but wouldn't summing it after using ```ne.evaluate()``` be faster? E.g. ```ne.evaluate("(-1)**n / (2*n + 1)").sum()```  I tried it for larger arrays n and it appeared to be much faster.

Comment: Also, a second question: It appears that ```numba``` with the ```sgn()``` function is the fastest option. It looks like you imported ```numpy``` --- did you use it? And if not, can an array/list be passed to a numba-compiled function (if I wanted to save each value before summing the array)? Or is numba just faster than using the numpy.sum() method?

Comment: @I_Don't_Code 1) Yes I also think that would be better here. 2) In this case actually not, but most of the time you will need numpy functions/methods. The main idea for using Numba or Numexpr (apart from optimizing away the (-1)**n) is avoiding temporary arrays, but you can of course also output an array and sum it up afterwards.
eg. simple example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765011/4045774 Avoid using lists if possible, there is only limited support and it can be a lot slower.

Answer (score 4):

3 suggestions (with speed computation):

define the Leibniz *point* not the cumulative sum:

```
def Leibniz_point(n):
    val = (-1)**n / (2*n + 1)
    return val
```

1) sum a list comprehension

```
%timeit sum([Leibniz_point(n) for n in range(100)])
58.8 µs ± 825 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit sum([Leibniz_point(n) for n in range(1000)])
667 µs ± 3.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

2) standard for loop

```
%%timeit
sum = 0
for n in range(100):
    sum += Leibniz_point(n)
61.8 µs ± 4.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
sum = 0
for n in range(1000):
    sum += Leibniz_point(n)
    729 µs ± 43.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**3) use a numpy array (suggested)**

```
%timeit Leibniz_point(np.arange(100)).sum()
11.5 µs ± 866 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit Leibniz_point(np.arange(1000)).sum()
61.8 µs ± 3.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: How does a generator expression compare to the list comprehension? I assume it is slower, but will take significantly less memory for large n.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi my expectation is about the same. the only difference that I know between list comprehensions and a `generator` is that a list comprehension is an evaluated generator stored into a `list` object while the generator is un-evaluated until needed. Since the `sum` function immediately requires arguments, the speed is very minimal (and I actually expect generators to perform slightly worse)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi just performed a check: generators performed slightly worse vs list comprehensions (about a 4% increase in processing time)

Comment: I see! Using ```Leibniz_point()``` lets you easily test this in different constructions. I was concerned that creation of the numpy array would slow the process down, but I suppose it's faster than the generation of each value ```i``` in the for loop?

Comment: @I_Don't_Code the reason why numpy is faster is the way it constructs collections is more efficient and I believe it has vectorized operations as well.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for operations involving collections of more than a few elements, `numpy` will be faster. A simple `numpy` implementation could be something like this:

```
def leibniz(n):
    a = np.arange(n + 1)
    return (((-1.0) ** a) / (2 * a + 1)).sum()
```

Note that you must specify that the numerator is a `float` with `1.0` on Python 2. On Python 3, `1` will be fine.

Comment: Or I could use ```from __future__ import division``` if  I wanted to avoid having to specify 1.0?

Comment: Yup, you could.

Comment: I think my misunderstanding of how numpy works is what caused me to even ask this question. I now see how easy it is that numpy is used to create an array of size n+1 and then use it to create two arrays, which can then be divided by one another, and its resulting array summed. Now it all seems trivial. Thank you! I'd upvote you, but someone downvoted my question, and now I'm below the threshold to vote (I'm new).