# is there a way to suppress divide by zero errors with Python Numba jitclass?

Tags: python, numba

I have a very large amount of Python code JIT-compiled as numba jitclasses, and under certain (but not all) unexplained conditions (e.g. certain arguments given to `__init__`), I get warnings about division by zero.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to generate a small block of code that reproduces the error, but  could anyone give me an idea of how to either find the cause of the divide-by-zero error or suppress it numpy-style?

Comment: Python has try/catch statements. What about them? Does the output contain a stack-trace with code lines?

Comment: In a normal njit function setting error_model="numpy" does exactly this. There are also significant speedups possible by setting this option.

Comment: @max9111, do you have any good examples of setting the error_model you could link to?

Comment: @Justlearnedit, try/catch statements are not compatible with numba.

Comment: Something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018898/4045774